# How to load data in breaks from Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Guys I have an ajax call on my page, which is being called on scroll down event (lazy loading).

This is the whole call :

```
function callMoreData()
{ $.ajax( {
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/api/values/getnotice",
                    dataType: "json",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        updateData(data);
                    },
                    error: function (x, e) {
                        alert('problem while fetching records!');
                    } });}

function updateData(data) {
    updateData = function (data) { };
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        BindNotice(value);
    });
}

function BindNotice(values)
{
 ...appending some div here with values...
}
```

now this call is returning all the data and display it all at once on first scroll event. What I want to do is, load the data in sets of two. For example, each loop gets executed on index 0 and 1 at first scroll, then on second scroll index 2 and 3 gets processed and then so on. How would I do about doing as? I have a very limited experience with JS/AJAX...

EDIT : CODE FROM CUSTOM LIBRARY :

```
$(".mainwrap .innnerwrap").mCustomScrollbar({
    autoDraggerLength:true,
    autoHideScrollbar:true,
    scrollInertia:100,
    advanced:{
        updateOnBrowserResize: true,
        updateOnContentResize: true,
        autoScrollOnFocus: false
    },
     callbacks:{
            whileScrolling:function(){WhileScrolling();},
            onTotalScroll: function () {
            callMoreData();
        }

    }
});
```

WebApi CODE :

```
[WebMethod]
[HttpGet]
public List<Notice> GetNotice()
{
    string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(con);
    string Query = "uSP_GetAllNotice";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Connection.Open();
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    Connection.Close();
    List<Notice> objNoticeList = new List<Notice>();
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Notice objNotice = new Notice();
        objNotice.Subject = row["subject"].ToString();
        objNotice.Date = Convert.ToDateTime(row["IssueDate"]);
        objNotice.Department = row["Department"].ToString();
        objNotice.Body = row["Body"].ToString();
        objNotice.NoticeImage = row["NoticeImage"].ToString();
        objNotice.Icon = row["Icon"].ToString();
        objNoticeList.Add(objNotice);
    }
    return objNoticeList;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to solve my problem. This is my ajax call

```
function callMoreData() {
                var RoleCodes = $('#hiddenRoleCode').val();
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/api/alert/getalerts?RoleCode=" + RoleCodes + "&LastAlertDate=" + formattedDate,
                        dataType: "json",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        async: true,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            $.each(data.data, function (index, value) {
                                update();
                                BindAlert(value);
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(x, e) {
                            alert('There seems to be some problem while fetching records!');
                        }

                    }
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure the server-side delivers only as mutch elements as you like, so that would be something like

```
[...]
type: "GET",
url: "/api/values/getnotice/" + start + '/' + amount,
dataType: "json",
[...]
```

start and amount have to be defined outside the function, in a higher scope, so it's available by the ajax function. While amount will be more or less constant, start can be calculated. 
One option would be, to increment it on the success function. 
Another solution can be, to count the divs you already appended to your DOM.

The result could be something like:

```
var amount = 2;
var start = 0;

function callMoreData(){ 
    $.ajax( {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/values/getnotice/" + start + '/' + amount,
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            updateData(data);
            start += amount;
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            alert('problem while fetching records!');
        } 
    });
}
```

I recommend NOT to put it in the global namespace, but to put it in a own one.

Comment: I dont get it.. my webapi url doesn't take `start` or `amount` values in it.. For example `/api/values/getnotice/0/2` doesn't work..

Comment: Of course you must programm that on the serverside, see my first sentence. Otherwise you would get ALL data everytime

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use paging parameters to get your data in chunks of two items at a time. Let the server handle the work of figuring out how to break the response data into two items per page.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/values/getnotice",
    data: {
        'PageSize': pageSize, 
        'Page': page
    },
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: true,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        updateData(data);
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        alert('problem while fetching records!');
    } 
});
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how to get this to work...basically a stored procedure is returning all the data. Are you suggesting that I should make a SP that sends two items per execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a global variable such as

```
Var time_scrolled = 0; //in the beginning
```

when you receive scrolldown event your indexes at each request will be `(time_scrolled*2)` and `(time_scrolled*2+1)` then you increase time_scrolled by 1 as `time_scrolled++;`

Hope this will solve your problem.

**Edited:**
complete code

```
    Var times_scrolled = 0; //in the beginning
    Var global_data = [];

        function callMoreData()
        { $.ajax( {
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "/api/values/getnotice",
                            dataType: "json",
                            crossDomain: true,
                            async: true,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {
                                global_data = data;
                            },
                            error: function (x, e) {
                                alert('problem while fetching records!');
                            } });}

    callMoreData(); //fetch data at the time of loading since it won't miss at first scroll
    function updateData(){
       var initial = times_scrolled*2;

            var final = initial+1;
            for(var i=initial;i<data.length && i<=final;i++)
            {
                BindNotice(global_data[i]);
            }
            times_scrolled++;

    }

        function BindNotice(values)
        {
         ...appending some div here with values...
        }


// modify custom library code to:

$(".mainwrap .innnerwrap").mCustomScrollbar({
    autoDraggerLength:true,
    autoHideScrollbar:true,
    scrollInertia:100,
    advanced:{
        updateOnBrowserResize: true,
        updateOnContentResize: true,
        autoScrollOnFocus: false
    },
     callbacks:{
            whileScrolling:function(){WhileScrolling();},
            onTotalScroll: function () {
            updateData();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: I understand the logic but how I implement this? how do I assign the value of index to (time_scrolled*2) or (time_scrolled*2+1) ?? and what about data at index 0 or 1 ?

Comment: Have edited answer and written complete code please take a look. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately applying your above code stops my scroll event i.e. no data is being loaded on scroll. Actually my CallMoreData is the function that has scroll functionality in custome JQuery library.

Comment: Can you show the full code ? so that I can help more.

Comment: Please see my edited question. That is all the code that is perform the scroll funcition as well as getting data from api...

Comment: Updated new complete code with custom library code. Please check it

Comment: I don't know why but still the scroll functionality doesn't work.

Comment: Check if there is any javascript error and confirm that scroll event is properly triggering.